# Main purpose / value of showing # of questions

Tags: discussion

When I go to stackoverflow I am presented with a fairly large random number (that changes almost by the minute).:

[image]

The image is not clickable - nor does it break down into how many unanswered questions exist, etc. (Not that I want it to break things down).  But what value does this serve the site?  We know that stackoverflow is a great site, we know that you can ask questions and hopefully receive answers, we know that lots of people are using the site.

But my question is what is the value of displaying this number?  To me its meaningless data that doesn't seem to bring at least for myself any value.  Maybe this number is great for some sort of key performance indicators like:

- How many total questions are on the site
- How many of those questions have been answered
- How many of those questions are bogus / spam

etc...But the typical end user doesn't really care?  Or do they?  Can we please get rid of this and use the real estate for something else?

Comment: Do you have any specific suggestions for a better use of the space?

Comment: Andrew - sure I'd be more interested to see a longer list of featured questions / answers from the site rather than how many questions the site has in total.  What is the value of knowing that at 3pm we had 7.5 million questions and in a few days we have 7.7 million?  You'd be surprised how many times I found "Hot Network Questions" very popular and clickable to the point I've joined some of these other sites.

Comment: I don't see how it's really taking space away from any of those things. It's in the right-hand column, followed by the "Featured on Meta" box, the Careers.SE box, Favorite Tags / Related Tags lists, and Hot Network Questions. Eliminating it would only shift those blocks up the page a tiny bit.

Comment: But andrew medico we could potentially increase the size of for instance "Featured On Meta".  I only mentioned the "Hot Network Questions" to give a prime example of having more of those serves me more purpose than knowing we have 8 million questions.

Comment: The page height isn't constrained. If the designers want to make any of the boxes in the right-hand column taller, they can just do it.

Comment: Let me ask you then Andrew, what value does 7.9 million questions serve you?

Comment: I think it's kind of interesting to see. Also, other question list pages (Featured, Unanswered, tags, etc) show the corresponding question count, so it's both consistent and allows viewers to see what percentage those other numbers are of the whole site.

Comment: Hmm in that case maybe shopping malls should have LED televisions that state the number of people who walked through the mall in total.

Comment: Why do we need to replace it with something? Why not just get rid of it and decrease the amount of clutter on the front page? I agree that it's a worthless feature. It may be interesting, but I don't see how it provides any real benefit.

Comment: @AndrewArnold - Okay now that I can agree with, its pointless unless you are some site admin who needs to know how many questions are on the site.

Comment: Presumably it's advertising, but would be helped if it was positioned near a similar number showing 'answered' (and/or possibly 'with-accepted-answers') metric. But I've not seen that number at all for a long, long while...

Answer (score 5):

This information is displayed on every site of the [StackExchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), so it is part of the look&feel of all the SE sites. When I navigate to another site of the network: it is interesting to have this information to get an idea of the size/activity of the site.

Why SO should be different ?

> We know that stackoverflow is a great site, we know that you can ask questions and hopefully receive answers, we know that lots of people are using the site

Probably true for SO-users, but not necessarily true for all StackExchange users...

Additionally, I'm sure that if this information is not easily visible : Meta-SO would be spammed with questions like this : "How many questions on SO ?"

Comment: An idea of the size/activity of the site...i like this when put that way.

Comment: Can you extrapolate yearly growth and estimate when SO can boast "Over 1,000,000,000 served"?