# Add separators to view counts?

Tags: feature-request

Can we please add a separator to the view counts?

Example:

[image]

It's easier to read as 545,262 rather than 545262.

Comment: How typical. I bet in the future you'll want to add separators to the "asked" field as well, eh? http://i.stack.imgur.com/NtOZX.png  ;)

Comment: Been asked before if I remember correctly.  The issue has been which separator since "," and "." can mean different things in different cultures (not saying this is right or wrong though given the precedence set by using commas in many places on the site)

Comment: I'd like to see it show something like **545k** views, just like the reputation in usercards or the people reached counter in your profile.

Comment: @JonasCz - That only works to estimate things out, it doesn't work if you want an absolute value.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - That is culture / region specific, there are different versions of so, say japanese / spanish that may use their own separator. That is my understanding of it...

Comment: @CubeJockey - By that time I would be dust so I don't care for it.

Comment: [E Notation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295952/621962), imo.

Comment: @canon I suggest everything > 10 years is replaced with "a long time ago". :P

Comment: The "what separator to use to be culture-independent" problem could be solved by using only a small space, that should be fairly clear yet it would aid in comprehending the numbers.

Comment: @Siguza in 100 years: in a galaxy far, far away.... 100 % agree, we need seperators.

Comment: To get around the culture specific problem, would it be possible to have this be a user specific option that would be used for the user logged in?  In other words, if I looked at the site and wasn't logged in, I'd see _viewed 545262 times_, but if I was logged in, and had selected **en-us**, I'd see _viewed 545,262 times_ and a user set for german (not sure of the lang code for that) would see _viewed 545.262 times_.

Comment: The reputation in the navbar has it, the flag count in the activity tab has it and the votes cast count has it.. along with numerous other things.. I see no valid reason why the view count shouldn't have it, cultural difference don't seem to matter on any of these other counts...

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on my comment, I think it would be better to just use the system used elsewhere on the site (does it have a name?), e.g., for the people reached statistic and for reputation. Thus, the views counter could be replaced with something like one of these:

- Viewed **545k times**
- **2.2 Million** views

Something like this would be a lot more user-friendly, as you don't have to mentally parse a long number (is that 100k or 1 million views?) and also consistent with the rest of the site.

I don't think accuracy is very important, since for such a large number of views it's bound to be off by a few thousand anyway (I vaguely remember that an SE dev said that the actual view count could be three times higher than what's shown, as the counter is quite strict), and I don't really care about the precise value that much.

A tooltip with the exact number would be good though, especially if you want to check by how much it has increased (how many people looked at this overnight?).

Comment: I asked something quite similiar and it was mass downvoted: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270008/main-purpose-value-of-showing-of-questions

Comment: @JonH Did you link to the wrong question in your comment?  That suggestion doesn't appear to be the same as what JonasCz is suggesting here.

Comment: Well its similar maybe I didn't :)

Comment: A tooltip for sure. All dates, reputation scores, and just about every other number on the site has a tooltip with the exact number.